# Replace ViewPager with another Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmenttransaction

I have a `Fragment` which contains a `ViewPager` which contains two `Fragment`s. In one of the `ViewPager`'s `Fragments` I have a list of items. When I click on the item, I want the whole `Fragment` containing the `ViewPager` to be replaced with a new `Fragment` which represents details about the item that was clicked (similar to starting a new `Activity` which replaces the existing one). I do like this:

```
CustomFragment fragment = new CustomFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

but it only replaces the `Fragment` of the `ViewPager` where the list of items is, not the whole `Fragment` that represents the `ViewPager`. How to achieve that the whole `ViewPager` `Fragment` would be replaced, not its child `Fragment`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get a reference to the `FragmentActivity` of the entire container that houses the tabs.

Comment: Could you give more explanation, please?